# Как вызвать функцию из строки?

Tags: c, c++

Есть много функций с одинаковым именем и разной цифрой в конце этого имени, то есть function1, function2, function3 и т.д. То есть, в определенном месте программы у меня есть счетчик, по которому я вызываю уже нужную из этих функцию, но как-то не хочется это делать через if или switch. Так вот, если сложить вместе имя функции function и счетчик, то можно ли как-то вызвать по этому имени функцию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам хочется такого, вы скорее всего неправильно построили архитектуру своей программы. Трюки, которые проходят в PHP или Javascript'е, не нужны в жёстко типизированных языках, в них другие выразительные средства.

---

Если всё же вам непременно хочется идти этим путём, заведите массив или карту.

Пример:

```
typedef double (*function_t)(double);

function_t[] functions =
    {
        function0,
        function1,
        function2,
        function3,
        function4
    };
unsigned int number_of_functions = sizeof(functions) / sizeof(functions[0]);

double call_by_index(unsigned int index, double argument)
{
    if (index >= number_of_functions)
    {
        // сообщите об ошибке, например, можете выбросить исключение
        // или вернуть NaN
    }
    return functions[index](argument);
}
```

Но, повторюсь, это неправильный путь. Если вы расскажете, что именно вы хотите запрограммировать, возможно, мы подскажем дизайн получше.

Comment: у меня на этот случай припасена задача. Суть задачи - на вход поступают данные вида "имя_команды параметры". где имя_команды - это несколько символов, а параметры - это просто строка с параметрами. Задача - исполнять команды.

Эта задача очень хорошо решается, если есть легкий способ вызвать функцию по ее имени. куча if'ов - плохой подход. В С++ хорошо решается с помощью map, который содержит указатели на функции-обработчики. В java - только if/case (мне простых методов не известно).

Comment: @kovadim: Почему if-case? В Java тоже есть аналогичные std::map() контейнеры. И как вывод можно хранить пары {String, CommandInterface}. Реализовав наследники от интерфейса CommandInterface получить то, что нужно, но на Java.

Comment: а туда можно добавить ссылки на методы?

Comment: Java 8 поддерживает лямбды, так что в виде лямбды.

Comment: лямбды - это просто сахар к интерфейсам с одним методом. А на них распространяются те же правила. Можно код?

Comment: @KoVadim: Для вашей задачи — имя, вводимое пользователем, вовсе не обязано совпадать с именем функции а исходнике. Так что реально нам нужно лишь привязать некую строку к функции (то есть, как вы и говорите, `map<string, ...>`).

Comment: @KoVadim: Вот исходник: http://pastebin.com/bQNsTHUU

Работает на http://www.compilejava.net/

---
Но в Java есть рефлексия, так что в принципе этот трюк не нужен.

Comment: @VladD, если правильно понимаю, это появилось в Java 8, а раньше так программировать было нельзя.

Помню, меня ужасно раздражало, что для имитации подобного поведения надо было для каждой функции делать свой класс (имена функций в классах одинаковые), а все эти классы наследовали общий интефейс.

--

И все это словоблудие вместо какого-нибудь `(*f)()`.

Comment: @avp: Раньше приходилось делать так: <http://pastebin.com/8ftngv92>. И всё из-за догмы о том, что «всё есть класс».

Это собственно было причиной, по которой MS поссорились с Oracle и написали свой C#, в котором указатели на функции (делегаты) были с самого начала.

Comment: Ага, здорово. Я до такой записи как-то не допер (и нигде не увидел).

Comment: @avp: Это на самом деле [анонимный класс](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Answer (score 2):

Можно.

Почитайте о разделяемых библиотеках (.so), посмотрите `man dlopen` (в винде тоже есть что-то похожее, свое, см. в сторону .dll).

Вот "для затравки" совсем небольшой ленивый примерчик:

```
avp@avp-xub11:lib$ cat t1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <dlfcn.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac <= 0 || ac > 100) { // а это кривая проверка "самовызова"
    printf("self-call: %s\n", (char *)ac);
    return 0;
  }
  void *my = dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW);
  if (!my) {
    printf("dlopen: %s\n", dlerror());
    exit(1);
  }

  int i;
  for (i = 1; av[i]; i++) {
    void (*f)() = dlsym(my, av[i]);
    if (!f)
      printf("function [%s] not found\n", av[i]);
    else
      f(av[i]), puts("");
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}

avp@avp-xub11:lib$ gcc t1.c -ldl -rdynamic
avp@avp-xub11:lib$ ./a.out f1 puts printf main
function [f1] not found
puts

printf
self-call: main

End
avp@avp-xub11:lib$
```

Программа открывает саму себя (загрузочный модуль) как разделяемую библиотеку, а также  наследует уже подключенные загрузчиком другие .so и вызывает функции, имена которых передаются в аргументах `main()`.

Только учтите, правильность передачи параметров никто не проверяет. Вы должны знать, какие параметры принимает функция и обязаны сами вызывать ее правильно.

Comment: @avp: Под виндой это работает только в случае [явно экспортируемых](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) функций. _Произвольную_ функцию так не вызвать.

Comment: Ну, в линуксе в известной мере тоже. Не зря же я компилирую с `-rdynamic`.

На самом деле, конечно, можно запрограммировать все (если таблица символов не затерта). Только возиться неохота... (кстати, Python умеет делать eval Сишных функций (да, gdb тоже может)).

Comment: @xinakapu, только вот с С++ напрямую такой вызов не пойдет, например, имя функции `int f2 (char *)` превратится в `_Z2f2Pc`.

Для крестов придется делать что-то в таком духе:

    extern "C" {
      int f2 (char *s) {
        printf("I am f2, arg: %s", s);
        return -strlen(s);
      }
    
      int f3 (char *s) {
        cout << "C++ func ";
        printf("I am f3, arg: %s", s);
        return 3 * strlen(s);
      }
    }

И в main заменить объявление (*f)(), скажем на

    int (*f)(char *) = (typeof(f))dlsym(my, av[i]);

Ну, я думаю, в принципе понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть библиотеку, в которой есть функция eval(), где-то видел такое, гугл ничего не дает, но я видел. Но если вы делаете серьезный проект, то лучше этого избежать, eval в любом языке - опасная функция, ее принцип основывается на передаче туда строки с кодом, его выполнении и получении какого-то объекта, любого возможного в пределах языка.

Либо еще есть механизм каррирования, гуглите.

Comment: @OlegUP: Эээ... Что-то я не представляю себе, как может работать функция `eval` в C++ — метаданных-то нет!